# Modify a Data Definition Language Trigger in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ddl-trigger

I have a database in SQL Server 2012, where I created a DDL trigger.

How can modify a data definition language trigger in SQL?

He don't have the 'Modify' option.

Comment: Drop & re-create your DDL trigger ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to modify the definition of a DDL trigger, you can either drop and re-create the trigger or redefine the existing trigger in a single step.

You can script dropping and re-creating trigger in SSMS using Script Database Trigger as > DROP And CREATE To...

You can redefine existing trigger using code:
[ALTER TRIGGER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176072)